# Git rebase and push mistake

Tags: git, github

I have a bit of an issue, and I'm not sure what to do. I am still learning git, so I hope you can help me out.

So I am working at a quite active repository. I have cloned the repo, and to suggest some changes I have to post pull requests.

My setup is as follows:

I have a master branch that I update from the upstream(set to the main repo master) with a rebase.

For each new issue, I create a new branch that I modify, push to github and apply as a PR.
This worked great until I wanted to update my local issue branch with the new master.

To do this I did a `fetch upstream` and `rebase` on my local master, and a merge of master into my branch.
Next I wanted to push my changes, but I received this error:

```
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
```

After looking over at the answers here, I decided to run `git pull --rebase` along with `git push` to apply the changes into the remote issue branch.

It was only after this that I realized what I have done. Since there where quite a few commits to the main master, the commit history is full of commits that I have not done.

Is there any way to fix this now? It would be great if I could rebase my whole issue branch on top of the newest master, but I am afraid to break anything along the way.

Comment: Can you add a visualization of some sort? This is very hard to follow without a concrete example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming nobody else is working on your issue branch you can just rewrite history and force push it.

Sometimes untangling what happened and why is more effort than just recreating your branch from scratch. `git cherry-pick` is your friend - here's how you can create a new local issue branch with only necessary commits.

Step by step, assuming your issue branch is called `my_issue`:

#### 1. just for backup, to keep the messy version - make a copy of it:

```
git checkout -b my_issue_messy
```

#### 2. go back to your my_issue branch to clean it up:

```
git checkout my_issue
```

#### 3. Get relevant commits.

Note down commits you want to keep: Look at the log in a more readable way - `git log --oneline --graph`, copy the SHAs of your issue fixes. Let's assume the commit SHA's are `1d1f76f`, `f63193d` and `d9f2fad` for the sake of the example.

#### 4. bring your remote up to date:

```
git fetch origin
```

#### 5. reset `my_issue` to currently latest master:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

#### 6. Cherry-pick your commits in one at a time:

```
git cherry-pick 1d1f76f
git cherry-pick f63193d
git cherry-pick d9f2fad
```

Boom! Now your branch stems from the state of current master, and you only have your relevant commits. What about the remote branch? It will complain as it won't realize the commits are duplicates (cherry-picking changed the time of the commit, and gave it a new SHA). May the `--force` be with you:

```
git push origin my_issue --force
```

If all is good and everybody is happy - you can delete your local `my_issue_messy` branch.